# Two loops in one function

Tags: php, loop

I am trying to get this function to work with jquery tabs, and I've gotten some of it to work. Right now the function correctly puts out the

```
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
etc..
</ul>
```

But it does not put out the second loop at all. I am not the most proficient at wordpress, not to mention php itself, so I am hoping for some help on how to correctly set up such a function.

```
function new_function($type='new_function') {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'tabs',
        'posts_per_page' => 10
    );
    //first loop puts out correctly so far.    
    $firstresult .= '<div id="tabs">';
    $firstresult .= '<ul>';
    $firstloop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($firstloop->have_posts()) {
        $firstloop->the_post();
        $firstresult .='<li><a href="#'.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
                    }
    $firstresult .='</ul>';
        return $firstresult;

    //the second loop does not work at all, but does not break the first part either.
    $result .= '<div id="tabs-container">';
    $loop = new WP_Query($args2);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();

    $result .='<div class="col-md-12">';
    $result .='<div class="quote-content"><blockquote>'.get_the_content().'</blockquote></div>';    
    $result .='<div class="quote-author"><p>' .get_the_title(). '</p></div>';
    $result .='</div>';
    }
    $result .= '</div>';
    $result .='</div>';
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to set up a new query, just use the first one. Replace:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args2 );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
     $loop->the_post();
```

...with:

```
$firstloop->rewind_posts();
while ( $firstloop->have_posts() ) {
     $firstloop->the_post();
```

Update: Missed a few other bugs in your code, here's the complete rework:

```
function new_function() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'tabs',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
    );

    $result = '<div id="tabs">';
    $result .= '<ul>';

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $result .= '<li><a href="#' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    }

    $result .= '</ul>';
    $result .= '<div id="tabs-container">';

    $loop->rewind_posts();
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();

        $result .= '<div class="col-md-12">';
        $result .= '<div class="quote-content"><blockquote>' . get_the_content() . '</blockquote></div>';
        $result .= '<div class="quote-author"><p>' . get_the_title() . '</p></div>';
        $result .= '</div>';
    }

    $result .= '</div>';
    $result .= '</div>';

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I tried replacing the three lines with your suggestion, but still only the first part is being displayed, and as before the code is not breaking anything, just seemingly ignoring the rest.

Comment: Missed a few more errors, see revised answer.